# For panel data models, what is the consequence of omitting predictors of current data point?

Tags: regression, panel-data

Suppose the data was collected once per month in 6 months, so 6 data points. The question is to examine how physical activity helps with better productivity later on. For that, the model is built to use the data of physical activity in the first 4 months to explain productivity in last 2 months. That is, the information of physical activity in the last 2 months is omitted, so is productivity in the first 4 months.

So what are problems with this model? And if there are, what is the better model to examine a question of this sort, i.e., effect of one factor but at later time? I think there may be a different model rather than involving data from all data points, because doing so seems to tell us just about the general effect, but not really the sort this question tries to address.

*EDIT:

For example, for any observation, the data prepared for this model looks like:

PA1 PA2 PA3 PA4 PDY5 PDY6

in which PA1-PA4 are physical activity from waves 1 to 4, PDY5 and PDY6 are productivity from data points 5 and 6. Originally, the data consists information of, say, PA5, PA6, and PDY1-PDY4 but they are left out.

Comment: Can you mathematically specify the model that you are stating? In particular, I am having difficulty understanding what "_That is, the information of physical activity in the last 2 months is omitted, so is productivity in the first 4 months._" means.

Comment: After some thought, it looks like the main concern with this misspecified model involves the issue of endogeneity. But I'm not sure if there are other problems.